# Get content after last / in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use javascript (or jQuery) to get the number value on the end of a url? The number could be multiple places but will always be whole (e.g 1-100)

```
http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/1 returns 1
http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12 return 12
http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12556456 returns 12556456
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **.split()** also possible

```
var str = "http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/333";
alert(str.split('/').pop())
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/275frkbu/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery. It is a basic string function. Use:

```
parseInt(url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

The above will give you a number, as we have used `parseInt()` so you can do numerical operations on it.

**Snippet**

```html
<script>
  function getNum (url) {
    return parseInt(url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), 10);
  }
</script>

<div><script>document.write(getNum("http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/1"));</script></div>
<div><script>document.write(getNum("http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12"));</script></div>
<div><script>document.write(getNum("http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12556456"));</script></div>
```

Comment: you should always specify the `radix` with `parseInt()`

Comment: @billyonecan Added. Why so?

Comment: Mainly because: *If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf` method to find last index of `/` along with `.substr()` to create substring from that index:

```
url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k0488tej/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a Regex to the `match()` method of the string:

```
var url = "http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12556456"
var id = url.match(/\/(\d+)$/)[1];
```

```js
var urls = [ "http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/1", "http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12", "http://localhost/mysite/#portfolio/12556456"]
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) 
    console.log(urls[i].match(/\/(\d+)$/)[1]);
```

Comment: `regex` will be slow as compared to `string` methods

Comment: Just providing an alternative to 3 of the same answer :)